# SQL - GROUP BY - Dynamic Columns

Tags: sql

How can we achieve this?

Actual Table:

```
.-------.---------.-------.------.---------.
| EmpId | Project | Title | Role |  Values |
|-------|---------|-------|----- |---------|
| 1     | aaa     |xxx    |     A|      100|
| 1     | aaa     |yyy    |     B|      120|
| 1     | aaa     |zzz    |     C|       90|
.-------.---------.-------.------.---------.
```

Target 1:

```
.-------.---------.-------.----.----.----.
| EmpId | Project | Title | A  | B  | C  |
|-------|---------|-------|--- |----|----|
| 1     | aaa     |xxx    | 100|null|null|
| 1     | aaa     |yyy    |null| 120|null|
| 1     | aaa     |zzz    |null|null|  90|
.-------.---------.-------.----.----.----.
```

Target 2:

```
.-------.---------.----.----.----.
| EmpId | Project | A  | B  | C  |
|-------|---------|--- |----|----|
| 1     | aaa     | 100| 120|  90|
.-------.---------.----.----.----.
```

Conditions:

1. In Target 1, Columns `A`/`B`/`C` are **dynamically** generated.(Pivot-ed, constant  change of column names).
   The columns A/B/C are not actually A/B/C. Its a result of a pivot table or stored procedure. It could be A/B/C/D or M/N or X/Y/Z.
2. Column `Title` is not at all important in Target 2.

Comment: I have no idea what "Pivot-ed based on constant change of column names" means. It is apparent to me you are not making any effort to clarify the question and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You can't do this in standard SQL, transgressing between data and schema, or it wouldn't be "relational" anymore. You may be able to achieve this with flavors of non-relational scripting which will depend on the flavor of SQL you are using, which you should specify in your question (and add the correct tag to it).

Answer (score 0):

Just use aggregation:

```
select EmpId, Project, max(A) as a, max(B) as b, max(C) as c
from t
group by EmpId, Project;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation. `MAX()` ignores `NULL` values:

```
SELECT empid, project, MAX(A) as A, MAX(B) as B, MAX(C) as C
FROM mytable
GROUP BY empid, project
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nuUnaJbwt77p1sK8Aj8mE6/0)**:

```
| empid | project | A   | B   | C   |
| ----- | ------- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1     | aaa     | 100 | 120 | 90  |
```

Comment: The columns A/B/C are not actually A/B/C. Its a result of a pivot table or some stored procedure. It could be A/B/C/D or M/N or X/Y/Z

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    T1.EmpId,
    T1.Project,
    T2.A,
    T3.B,
    T4.C
FROM
    Table T1
LEFT JOIN
    Table T2 ON
        T2.EmpId=T1.EmpId
        AND T2.Project=T1.Project
        AND T2.A IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN
    Table T3 ON
        T3.EmpId=T1.EmpId
        AND T3.Project=T1.Project
        AND T3.B IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN
    Table T4 ON
        T4.EmpId=T1.EmpId
        AND T4.Project=T1.Project
        AND T4.B IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Please review the conditions.

Comment: I can't make sense of your comment. Be more descriptive when asking for help.

Comment: The columns A/B/C are not actually A/B/C. Its a result of a pivot table or some stored procedure. It could be A/B/C/D or M/N or X/Y/Z

Comment: @user2799083 You can't do that in standard SQL, transgressing between data and schema, or it wouldn't be "relational" anymore. You may be able to achieve this with flavors of non-relational scripting which will depend on the flavor of SQL you are using, which you should specify in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte (id,pro,title,rol,val) as (
select 1,'aaa','xxx','A',100 union all
select 1,'aaa','yyy','B',120 union all
select 1,'aaa','zzz','C',90)
select id,pro,title,[a],[b],[c] from (
select * from cte ) a
pivot 
(max(val) for rol in ([a],[b],[c])) aa


with cte (id,pro,title,rol,val) as (
select 1,'aaa','xxx','A',100 union all
select 1,'aaa','yyy','B',120 union all
select 1,'aaa','zzz','C',90)
select id,pro,max([a]) A,max([b]) B,max([c]) C from (
select * from cte ) a
pivot 
(max(val) for rol in ([a],[b],[c])) aa
group by id,pro
```